# Dialog on Android KitKat seems to be cut

Tags: android, dialog, android-4.4-kitkat

I used dialog theme for an Activity and it works fine on Android <= 4.3 but not on the latest KitKat 4.4.
Here's a screenshot of the problem:

[image: dialog android 4.4 problem]

Top of the layout is missing.
You can see that the bounds seems to be cut.

I'm using an Android emulator to test the app, so I don't know if the problem is due to the virtual machine or due to some other reason.

Comment: Change the question title to a proper one, it doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Done, sorry I forgot to change it ^^

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can solve the problem to be cut from below code.

```
dialog.getWindow().setFlags(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: Not sure why this is necessary, but appreciate the finding.  I just started noticing this on several application and other approaches did not work.

Comment: It is works. Thanks a lot! But I hate so much Android workarounds.

Answer (score 9):

You should extend the Dialog and in the onCreate call the following method:

```
@TargetApi(14)
public void toggleHideBar() {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 18) {
        return;
    }

    // The UI options currently enabled are represented by a bitfield.
    // getSystemUiVisibility() gives us that bitfield.
    int uiOptions = getWindow().getDecorView().getSystemUiVisibility();
    int newUiOptions = uiOptions;
    boolean isImmersiveModeEnabled =
            ((uiOptions | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY) == uiOptions);
    if (isImmersiveModeEnabled) {
        Log.d("dialog", "Turning immersive mode mode off.");
    } else {
        Log.d("dialog", "Turning immersive mode mode on.");
    }

    // Status bar hiding: Backwards compatible to Jellybean
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16 && (newUiOptions & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) <= 0) {
        newUiOptions ^= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    }

    // Immersive mode: Backward compatible to KitKat.
    // Note that this flag doesn't do anything by itself, it only augments the behavior
    // of HIDE_NAVIGATION and FLAG_FULLSCREEN.  For the purposes of this sample
    // all three flags are being toggled together.
    // Note that there are two immersive mode UI flags, one of which is referred to as "sticky".
    // Sticky immersive mode differs in that it makes the navigation and status bars
    // semi-transparent, and the UI flag does not get cleared when the user interacts with
    // the screen.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 18 && (newUiOptions & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY) <= 0) {
        newUiOptions ^= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
    }

    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(newUiOptions);
}
```

Comment: I think this should be the better and accepted answer, no hard-coded things in here!

Answer (score 3):

Finally, I tried to do something with the new FullScreen Immersive mode available in Android 4.4. [Android FullScreen](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/fullscreen.html)

Just put this in the **onResume** of the **"dialog"** activity, and that allow you to use dialogs in a fullscreen activity, without the top cutting :)

Edit : Added a compatibility check for the target version, setSystemUiVisibility is implemented in Api 11, but it seem to need that "patch" only for android 4.4  )

```
// Only for Api >=4.0 
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
    int mUIFlag = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION // I removed this
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION; // and this to keep the navigation bar
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(mUIFlag);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Hacketo for the clue. However the following flags seem to be sufficient for keeping the top area from cutting
`getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);`

Comment: For me, only the View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN flag was necessary (but I'm not trying to hide the navigation bar). Also, for those having issues, try getDialog.getWindow.etc...

Comment: It needs to be in onResume because backgrounding the app will cause the dialog to get cut off again otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem, but with using a custom dialog. Unfortunately, I couldn't post my screenshot here.

I tested with a few different options, and looks like running the parent activity in fullscreen mode affects this. If I remove the following code, the dialog seems to work fine.

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

I noticed this after getting the 4.4 KitKat update on a Google Nexus 7 (first version). Also, it doesn't seem to make a difference if I have the dialog's title present or not.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line of code in your activity's **onCreate** method.

> getWindow().setFlags(0x04000000, 0x04000000); // FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS

Comment: Hi! Welcome to the site! Would you care to expand your answer with any more details?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem as you describe and show in your screenshots. The problem happened only on KitKat.

In my case it happened on some popup dialogs which used a custom style. Next is a style which reproduces the problem when applie to a dialog. Notice the first line, which has the attribute **parent="android.Theme"**, by removing that attribute the problem got solved.

```
<style name="transparent_low_dim" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimAmount">0.3</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
</style>
```

To fix it I removed the parent attribute so the first line would look now like next:

```
<style name="transparent_low_dim">
```