# Custom dialog on android Kitkat 4.4 cuts top area

Tags: android, dialog, android-dialog, android-4.4-kitkat, customdialog

In my android app, i am using `custom dialog` in my `activity`. I have given style to this custom dialog for transparent background. I am facing weird issue on Kitkat 4.4. The dialog gets cut from top side only on `Kitkat 4.4`.Devices with sdk level < 4.4 gives proper output according to my requirement. Why its is like this? Pleas help me to solve this issue.I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121711/dialog-on-android-kitkat-seems-to-be-cut) link but not getting how to implement it with my requirement.
Thank you.

Code:

```
 public void showGameOverDialog(int score) {

        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Level1Activity_Room.this,
                R.style.DialogBackground);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.gameover_dialog_layout);         
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
}
```

R.style.DialogBackground :

```
 <style name="DialogBackground" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally i solved this issue with some modification in my existing code. Also changed Target level to `Android 4.4` from `Project->Right Click->Android`

```
    public void showGameOverDialog(int score) {
        final Dialog dialog = new customeDialogClass(Level1Activity_Room.this,
                R.style.DialogBackground);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.gameover_dialog_layout);
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
dialog.show();
}
```

customeDialogClass.java

```
 @TargetApi(14)
public class customeDialogClass extends Dialog {

    public customeDialogClass(Context context) {
        super(context);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 18) {
            return;
        }

        // The UI options currently enabled are represented by a bitfield.
        // getSystemUiVisibility() gives us that bitfield.
        int uiOptions = getWindow().getDecorView().getSystemUiVisibility();
        int newUiOptions = uiOptions;
        boolean isImmersiveModeEnabled = ((uiOptions | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY) == uiOptions);
        if (isImmersiveModeEnabled) {
            Log.e("log1---", "Turning immersive mode mode off.");
        } else {
            Log.e("log2-----", "Turning immersive mode mode on.");
        }

        // Status bar hiding: Backwards compatible to Jellybean
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16
                && (newUiOptions & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) <= 0) {
            newUiOptions ^= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 18
                && (newUiOptions & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY) <= 0) {
            newUiOptions ^= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
        }

        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(newUiOptions);
    }

    public customeDialogClass(Context context, boolean cancelable,
            OnCancelListener cancelListener) {
        super(context, cancelable, cancelListener);
    }

    public customeDialogClass(Context context, int theme) {
        super(context, theme);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 18) {
            return;
        }

        // The UI options currently enabled are represented by a bitfield.
        // getSystemUiVisibility() gives us that bitfield.
        int uiOptions = getWindow().getDecorView().getSystemUiVisibility();
        int newUiOptions = uiOptions;
        boolean isImmersiveModeEnabled = ((uiOptions | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY) == uiOptions);
        if (isImmersiveModeEnabled) {
            Log.e("log1---", "Turning immersive mode mode off.");
        } else {
            Log.e("log2-----", "Turning immersive mode mode on.");
        }

        // Status bar hiding: Backwards compatible to Jellybean
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16
                && (newUiOptions & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) <= 0) {
            newUiOptions ^= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 18
                && (newUiOptions & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY) <= 0) {
            newUiOptions ^= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
        }
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(newUiOptions);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem not in kitkat 4.4, i think problem is in the R.layout.gameover_dialog_layout for screen support

Comment: But it looks perfect in other devices having sdk < 4.4. So there is no problem in my layout.

Answer (score 0):

It usually goes through a title bar that is added in Android 4.4 or lower versions.
It is solved by adding the following line to the custom dialog.

```
dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```