# overlapped by status bar when dialog fragment is shown, only in Android4.4

Tags: android, statusbar, android-dialogfragment, android-4.4-kitkat

My problem happens only on Android 4.4 Kitkat and when I show a dialog fragment, part top of it will be overlapped by status bar. How can I deal with this issue? It's a Kitkat bug?

See screenshot here:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: I have the same issue with Android 4.4.2 and a transparent status bar

Comment: Does this have anything to do with immersive mode? I'm thinking so, take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121711/dialog-on-android-kitkat-seems-to-be-cut

Comment: @Bryan, no immersive mode in my app

Comment: Would you mind verifying this still occurs on the L preview emulator? If it's still occurring, please file a bug at https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/wiki/FilingIssues?tm=3 so we can get it fixed ASAP.

Comment: That GUI doesn't follow Androids design guidelines. It looks more like a iOS interface.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dialog choiceDialog = new Dialog(this);
    choiceDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    Window window = choiceDialog.getWindow();
    int y = findViewById(R.id.bannerview).getTop();
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = window.getAttributes();
    lp.y = y;
    lp.dimAmount = 0;`enter code here`
    lp.windowAnimations = android.R.anim.fade_in;
    window.setAttributes(lp);
    choiceDialog.setContentView(R.layout.conversation_action_dialog);
```

i did this to show dialog but its not a dialog fragment may helps u