# Notification Bar does cut my views

Tags: android-layout, android-fragments, android

I have a really strange behaviour on my nexus 4 (running android 4.4).
Although I set these Flags in my MainActivity

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
activity.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
activity.getActionBar().hide();
```

My Views (e.g. DialogFragments) do get cut by the invisible NotifictaionBar, see the attached Screenshot at the top.

Does anybody have a hint for me what to do, which flags I have to set?
Thanks in advance.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out: In this post there is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20281449/855950

I had to set this flags in my MainActivity

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
getActionBar().hide();  //Be carefull of target API
```

in the `OnCreate` of my DialogFragment this line (to hide the Title)

```
setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog);
```

and in the onCreateView of my Dialog this line:

```
getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
getDialog().getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Works for me :)