# Unity Facebook SDK: Dialogs Cut Off

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

When I show the Share or Send Request dialog from my Unity app on Android, they seem to be cut off at the top.

[image: picture shamelessly taken from the other question]

There is a question about exactly the same issue using the regular (Java) Facebook Android SDK: [Dialog on Android KitKat seems to be cut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121711/dialog-on-android-kitkat-seems-to-be-cut), but all of the solutions there require direct access to the Java classes.

Has anyone seen this issue with the Facebook Unity SDK? Is there a way to fix this, apart from using the Java SDK instead of the Unity SDK?

I'm using Unity 4.6.3 and version 6.2.2 of the SDK.

Comment: I am using version 6.2.1. No such issues here. Just downgrade and check in a blank project.

Comment: We have refactored and reworked our dialogs in the latest **beta** sdks (v7.x). I would try it and see if you are having issues there too. see [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/beta/webgl#dialogs)